# Forms: input + label as a placeholder

Tags: css, forms, input, label, placeholder

I'm working on adaptive placeholders for a form. Inspired by this http://blog.circleci.com/adaptive-placeholders I use `<label>` and give it style to make it look like a normal placeholder.

Like this:

```
input[type="text"][required] + label[placeholder]:before {
                content: attr(placeholder);
                display: inline-block;
                margin: 0 10px;
                padding: 0;
                color: #999999;
                white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Normally I target the placeholder for styling (eg. giving it a validation error class) like this:

```
.error::-webkit-input-placeholder {
                color: #000;
            }
```

My first thought would be the following to set the .error class, but it doesn't work:

```
.error::-webkit-input[type="text"][required] + label[placeholder]:before {
                color: #000;
            }
```

Any suggestions on how I properly can apply a CSS class for the method used above?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/34ye51t5/

Thanks.

Comment: "Any suggestions on how I properly can apply a CSS class for the method used above?" to do what?

Comment: The placeholder text color is #999999. When I hit 'submit' on an empty form (no input fields filled), the background color of all unvalidated fields is set to a dim red color. The light grey color of #999999 is barely visible against the red background. I would like to have the label/placeholders to change color in the same operation.

Comment: can you post a jsfiddle or codepen?

Comment: Sure, fiddle added :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're running into specificity issues. Adding the following CSS works, but I would consider re-factoring your code to help avoid these problems.

```
input[type="text"].error + label[data-placeholder]:before{
  color: white;
}
```

First of all `placeholder` is [not a valid attrinbute for a label](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/label) - it's for inputs only. You could change this to a data attribute, but I don't really see the point in this, you might as well just use the label as follows (alt is also not a valid attribute

```
<label for="last_name">Last name</label>
```

You'll then need to adjust the positioning etc. of this label.

I would also consider adding a class to a wrapper for the label/input combination for better control and to avoid said specificity issues. I've done a quick example using [BEM](https://en.bem.info/) naming conventions using sass as a preprocessor. This isn't meant to replicate the behavior of your code, but should act as a good starting point.

http://codepen.io/jaycrisp/pen/pgQbWd

You can then add the error class as a 'modifier' to each element to allow you to style these independently e.g. `.fancy__input--error` and not rely on using things like the + selector.

Comment: Excellent! That did the trick. Thank you for your insights on this issue.